# Firmware error in kernel compilation

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, kernel, firmware, odroid

I have created  a `custom kernel 4.1.5(latest)` on the `**odroid xu3**` device as mentioned in Arm DS5 streamline configuration, Odroid has `kernel 3.1.82-35` already,

after `make menu config`
during `make`

it gives a **firmware error**, i.e:-

> make[1]:  No rule to make target `firmware/edid/1024x768.bin', needed by`firmware/edid/1024x768.bin.gen.o'. Stop.
>   make:  [firmware] Error 2"

Can anyone tell me what should i do, I am new to this.

Comment: Perhaps you meant 3.1**0**.82.

Comment: Ohh, yes typing error sorry!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firmware is missing. You should check whether this firmware is needed or not. If it is necessary, download it and place it in the proper place. Otherwise, you can delete the rules in the Makefile.

Comment: Ok. I have checked it online, i did not found this firmware anywhere. Also in the makefile of linux kernel 4.1.5, I am not able to find about this firmware anything.

Comment: check firmware/Makefile or firmware/edid/Makefile.